# Initialize an array of static structures

Tags: c++

Is it possible to initialize an array of static structures?
I know how to do it in code, but is it possible to do it statically?

Like this:

```cpp
struct HeadSensorMap {
    int MinSensorDistance[ 5 ];
    unsigned char TurnDirection;
    int TurnAngle;
};

struct HeadSensorMap HeadSensorMapSet[ 32 ] ;
HeadSensorMapSet[ 0 ].HeadSensorMap = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 'P' , 90 };
```

Comment: You can use list initialisation.

Comment: about "I tried to show and example but the edit just keeps telling to inset by four spaces. I tried this but know way will it let me post the structure" => there's a format for sharing code in stackoverflow.  Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
struct HeadSensorMap {
    int MinSensorDistance[ 5 ];
    unsigned char TurnDirection;
    int TurnAngle;
};

HeadSensorMap HeadSensorMapSet[ 32 ] = {
    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 'P', 90},
    // ...
};
```